# How to Delete Contact details from addressbook

Tags: iphone

I have a project in which i want to delete contact details of address book of a particular person...on button click..

I have tried to modify,add and edit the record and was successful in that but not able to delete the record..

Please help me with that...
Thanks...in advance

Answer (score 0):

use ABAddressBookRemoveRecord

refer to:-
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ABAddressBookRemoveRecord](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRemoveRecord)